# Kosaraju algorithm - computing SCCs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, kosaraju-algorithm

For a given directed graph **G** I need to compute its strongly connected components (SCCs) using Kosaraju's algorithm. As far as I've understood the steps of the algorithm are as follows:

1. Let **G**rev = **G** wit all arcs reversed
2. Run **DFS** (Depth-First Search) on **G**rev to compute the finishing times of the nodes
3. Run **DFS** on **G** to discover SCCs

I have managed to find the correct finishing times of all the nodes. I partially understand that I should assign the finishing times to its respective node values, reverse the graph **G**rev, and run DFS again on the reversed graph (now **G**) with the finishing times as the node values processing nodes in decreasing order of finishing times. Is my understanding correct? If so, how can I code it up?

Here's where I got to so far:

```
# Number of elements in graph + 1
graph_elem = 10

def dfs_iterative(graph):
    # variable initialization

    for i in range(graph_elem - 1, 0, -1):
        stack.append(i)

        while stack:
            v = ... # Get top of stack

            # If the top of the stack is not explored, or if any of the children of 
            # the node on the top of the stack are unexplored, then continue the traversal
            if ...:
                #Mark explored

                for head in graph[v]:
                    if head not in explored:
                        stack.append(head)
                    # Prevent the loop iterating through all of the children like BFS

            else:
                # Get finishing time for v

    return finishing_times

# Graph represented in a list through edges
# index represents the tail node of the edge, and g[index] is the head node
# Example edges of g: (1, 4), (2, 8), (3, 6), etc.
g = [[], [4], [8], [6], [7], [2], [9], [1], [5, 6], [7, 3]]
rev_g = [[], [7], [5], [9], [1], [8], [3, 8], [4, 9], [2], [6]]
fin_times = dfs_iterative(rev_g)
```

The `fin_times` should be `{3: 1, 5: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 6: 5, 9: 6, 1: 7, 4: 8, 7: 9}`, and as previously mentioned it is correct. What do I actually have to do with `fin_times` now?

Also, the reason I am doing it iteratively and not recursively is the fact that the input file for the assignment is too big and the program would reach recursive limits.

**Edit**: Upon answering the question I realized that the question was not in accordance with the course's Honor Code. I edited the question to exclude parts of the code that may give away the solution to the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my question was only:

> What to do with the `fin_times` dictionary?

I'll provide the solution only to that question as to not offer the complete solution to the assignment.

So the answer seemed to be reversing the `fin_times` dictionary so that the keys become the values, and vice-versa:

`order = dict((v, k) for k, v in finishing_times.items())`

`{1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 8, 5: 6, 6: 9, 7: 1, 8: 4, 9: 7}`

Then we run **DFS** on **G** processing nodes in decreasing order of finishing times (in this case vertex 7 with the finishing time 9). Corresponding to the code in the question, instead of:

```
for i in range(graph_elem - 1, 0, -1):
        stack.append(i)
```

We write:

```
order = dict((v, k) for k, v in finishing_times.items())

for i in range(graph_elem - 1, 0, -1):
        vertex = order[i]
        if vertex not in explored:
            stack.append(vertex)
            explored.add(vertex)

            // DFS code and SCC size computation...
```